# How do I temporarily change directory and assign a variable a value

Tags: shell

```
(cd /home/sharan/code/darknet; darknet_result=$(git remote -v | grep $SD_Darknet))
echo $darknet_result
```

The result for `$daknet_result` is just an empty space . How would I get the varaible to be assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
darknet_result=$(cd /home/sharan/code/darknet; git remote -v | grep "$SD_Darknet")
```

The problem in your code is that `(` `)` starts a new subshell, so any variable assignments there are not visible in the parent shell.

Comment: How would I go about not changing my working directory and getting a variable assigned?